# SQL syntax for retrieving from a different table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hi I have two tables User and Pictures im trying to pull the pathname from my pictures table (userid=1) is the same in both related with pk, but Im unsure how to select firstname etc from user table and select picturepath from pictures table?

Im also wondering if the img path will be set correctly if i use the commented out line?

```
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=1", cn);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
            Age.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(3));
            Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(4));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `D[ate]O[f]B[irth]` to a field called `Age`? That's not the same.

Comment: its not but it will be changed later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch data from two related tables in one query you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT
    User.FirstName,
    User.SecondName,
    User.Aboutme,
    User.DOB,
    Picture.PicturePath
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Pictures
ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID
WHERE User.UserID=1
```

Then, yes, you can uncomment that last line.

Comment: Unknown column 'User.User' in 'on clause'

Comment: no no its fine it works i ment the previous post u made this one works tho, but I have a problem the specified Image1 url path isnt loading in the image control on the asp page?